# Error loading 'teamcity' file when running `Cucumber ./features`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

Currently, I am trying to use Cucumber to run tests in a Ruby on Rails application.

```
cucumber ./features --tags ~@javascript
```

Whenever I run this command however, I get the following error related to `teamcity`

```
Using the default profile...
cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter (LoadError)
```

I've tried using solutions given in other related questions but can't seem to get it to work, unless there's something I'm missing.

Versions

- Ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162)
- Rails 3.2.21
- Ubuntu 16.04

Full Error

```
cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter (LoadError)
/home/d/dev/sareform/features/support/env.rb:22:in `require'
/home/d/dev/sareform/features/support/env.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/home/d/dev/sareform/features/support/env.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/d/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.21'
gem 'rake', '10.4.2' 
....

gem 'jquery-rails'#, "3.1.2" #old version 1.0.19
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rvm'
gem 'rvm-capistrano',  require: false
....
gem 'coffeebeans'
....
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.6'
gem 'custom_configuration', '~> 0.0.2'

group :test, :test_ram do
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'guard-zeus'
  gem 'kaminari-rspec'
end

group :cucumber, :test, :test_ram do
  gem 'i18n'
  gem "rack"
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rb-inotify'#, '~> 0.9'
  gem 'libnotify'
  gem 'ffi', '>= 1.0.11'
  gem "factory_girl_rails" #was 1.6.0
  gem "guard"#, "~> 1.1.0"#was 0.10.0
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "guard-livereload"
  gem "guard-cucumber", "~>1.2.2" #was 0.7.5
  gem "guard-bundler"
  gem 'guard-webrick', "~> 0.1.2" #was 0.1.0
  gem 'guard-test'
  gem 'spork', '> 0.9.0.rc'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'selenium-client'
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.45.0"
  gem 'cucumber_statistics'
end


group :development, :test, :test_ram do
  gem 'email_spec'
#  gem 'mocha'#was 0.10.4
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'rspec-rails' #was 2.8.0
  gem "rspec-activemodel-mocks"
  gem "launchy", '~> 2.1.0' #previously no version identified
  gem "geordi"
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem "zeus"
  gem "parallel_tests"
  gem 'zeus-parallel_tests'
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'jasmine-sinon-rails'
  gem 'jasmine-jquery-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me as if your path is broken. You have a relative path and I don't think TeamCity uses the same project root as you assume it does.

My approach would be to start with an absolute path. Get the system to run and then see if it is possible to use relative paths.